# json data into individual csv file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have many `json` files under `/json/reports/` location and for each `json` file the output need to be converted into `csv` file individually.

I have the following python code to convert.

```py
import pandas as pd
import glob
path = '/json/reports/*.json'
files = glob.glob(path)
for file in files:
    f = open(file, 'r')
    jsonData = pd.read_json(f.read())
    jsonData.to_csv(f.name+".csv")
    f.close()
```

**One of my json file (First few lines) output as follows.**

```json
  [
    {
        "api_result": "KEY_NAME",
        "ml_result": "VALUE",
        "line_data_list": [
            {
                "line": "54A2FF607A6dsewroadeEOERD> |-",
                "line_num": 9053,
                "path": "/home/user/src/common/race/flow/prog_flow.mk",
                "value": "WOERJFOQDKSDFKKASDF0",
                "variable": null,
                "entropy_validation": true
            }
        ],
        "ml_part": 0.994396984577179,
        "rule": "GCP Client ID",
        "severity": "high"
    },
    {
        "api_result": "NOT_AVAILABLE",
        "ml_result": "NOT_AVAILABLE",
        "line_data_list": [
            {
                "line": "-----BEGIN Result-----",
                "line_num": 19873,
                "path": "/home/user/test/linux/ops/format.key",
                "value": "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE",
                "variable": null,
                "entropy_validation": false
            }
        ],
        "ml_part": null,
        "rule": "Certificate",
        "severity": "low"
    },
 .....
 .......
 ..........
```

**Problem:-**:-

The above python code writing `line_data_list` list values (`line`, `line_num`, `path`, `value`, `variable`, & `entropy_validation`) in single column, but I need each value in a seprate column. (Ie specified in below format).

**Expected output csv per json file:-**

| Sl.no | api_result | ml_result | line_data_list | line | line_num | path | value | variable | entropy_validation | ml_part | rule | severity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | KEY_NAME | VALUE |  | 54A2FF607A6dsewroadeEOERD | 9053 | /home/user98/src/common/race/flow/prog_flow.mk | WOERJFOQDKSDFKKASDFO | null | TRUE | 0.994396985 | GCP Client ID | high |
| 2 | NOT_AVAILABLE | NOT_AVAILABLE |  | -----BEGIN Result----- | 19873 | /home/user/test/linux/ops/format.key | -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE | null | false | null | Certificate | low |
| 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Need help to print each in separate column.

Comment: Did you try this `pd.json_normalize(lst, 'line_data_list', ['api_result', 'ml_result', 'line', 'line_num', 'path', 'value', 'variable', 'entropy_validation'], 
                    record_prefix='line_data_list_', errors='ignore')` where `lst` is the list of jsons that you pasted in the question

Comment: @XXavier, Not yet. let me try now. if possible can you help me with complete code?

Comment: You can append your individual jsons to a list and use this `pd.json_normalize(lst, 'line_data_list', ['api_result', 'ml_result'], 
                    record_prefix='line_data_list_', errors='ignore')`. Then you can save the pandas dataframe to csv

Comment: `jsonData = pd.json_normalize(lst, 'line_data_list', ['api_result', 'ml_result'],                      record_prefix='line_data_list_', errors='ignore')` says - `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'json_normalize'`

Comment: Does this work `from pandas import json_normalize`

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):`
  `File "json_to_csv.py", line 3, in <module>`
    `from pandas import json_normalize`
`ImportError: cannot import name json_normalize`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this [json file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oFgEiVYokv00w4K93frAetjJjzL8TEF7/view?usp=sharing):

```
df = pd.read_json("mydata.json")
t = df['line_data_list'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[0]))
pd.concat([df, t], axis=1)
```

In your case:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
path = '/json/reports/*.json'
files = glob.glob(path)
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_json(file)
    t = df['line_data_list'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[0]))
    df = pd.concat([df, t], axis=1)
    df.to_csv(f'{file[:-5]}.csv')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide one of that files?

Comment: It is updated in question, Please have a look.

Comment: The question contains the part that I used. I mean one complete json file.

Comment: Oh it has 1000+ lines, So i have uploaded another set in question, Plz have a look.

Comment: See if it helps now or not.

Comment: In this approach need to hard-code each json file's content, Since i have `2000+ json files` in `/json/reports/` location and each file has many entries like given above, So it would be difficult to add them manually. Looking script to perform in an automated way

Comment: What do you mean by hard coding? just use a loop to iterate over your 2000+ files and convert the above code to a function and apply that to each files in loop.

Comment: If you clear the problem I would help.

Comment: Hard code means - ` j1 =` section i need to provide each `json' file's entry manually. i'm finding difficulties with `line_data_list` and its `values` in writing in csv similar like other columns. Kindly help me on to achieve this. it would be great helpful. thanks.

Comment: No , you do not need! It is just an example. If I had your json files I did not write the answer like this.

Comment: The simplest approach is to read the json files as text file then do the continue of code.

Comment: ok, In this approach in the `j1 = ` section i need to provide my `/json/reports/` path something like this  `/json/reports/*.json` ?

Comment: Probably yes...

Comment: Just use the new approach i provided in my answer.

Comment: Let me know if the problem solved or not.

Comment: I'm finding difficulties still working on it, If possible could you update the complete code in your answer section.

Comment: look at the answer. It is complete. I have uploaded sample json file too based on your question.

Comment: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "json_to_csv.py", line 7, in <module>
    t = df['line_data_list'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[0]))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3505, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3623, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'line_data_list'

Comment: So there is some difference between the file produced the error with the example I developed the answer based on. You should refer to the specified file to find the reason.

Comment: If you could not find the problem share the file that produced the error, so I can help.

Comment: Json file looks not an issue. The above issue comes from python installed path.

Comment: I do not think that is the problem.

Comment: Ok. Line no - 7 having some issue. Looking into it.

Comment: What is in that line?

Comment: `t = df['line_data_list'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[0]))`

Comment: No, I mean in the data that caused the error.

Comment: You know, it is what I said in some comments ago, the data is not in the expected format. If you look at the very end of the last comment you can see: line_data_list is not there in your json file.

Comment: Right many `json` files having `[]` hence it was failing earlier, Now it finished successfully, However now `line_data_list` list value prints in one column and also each in separate column as well. And all `json` data printed in single excel.

Comment: use del df['line_data_list'] to drop the non-wanted col.

Comment: My code for writing is an example again. You should set desired name for each file dynamically in the for loop.

Comment: Your problem solved?

Comment: No, I'm struggling to print each json in separate csv file dynamically.

Comment: Where do you want to save your output?

Comment: In same json file folder with json filename as csv.. Example - `file.json` as `file.csv`

Comment: Look at the answer again.

Comment: Let me know your state.

Comment: Thanks a lot Keramat, it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unpack your line_data_list key-value pairs so they occur on the same level as your other columns. Something like what I've written below would work.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import json

path = '/json/reports/*.json'
files = glob.glob(path)
for file in files:
    f = open(file, 'r')
    json_dict = json.load(f)
    line_data = json_dict[0].pop("line_data_list")
    {json_dict.update(header, val) for header, val in line_data.items()}
    jsonData = pd.from_dict(json_dict, orient="records")
    jsonData.to_csv(f.name+".csv")
    f.close()
```

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):`
 `File "json-to-csv.py", line 10, in <module>`
   `line_data = json_dict.pop("line_data_list")`
`TypeError: an integer is required`

Comment: Sorry I forgot the columns was a list of dict, not just a dict. if it's always a list of 1 item, I have edited the code so it should work. If it can be more items, you will need to handle it differently depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Now it shows - `Traceback (most recent call last):`
  `File "json-to-csv.py", line 11, in <module>`
    `{json_dict.update(header, val) for header, val in line_data.items()}`
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'`

Comment: Try editing to "in line_data[0].items()"

Comment: `{json_dict.update(header, val) for header, in line_data[0].items()}` updated now getting following errors -  `File "json_to_csv.py", line 11, in <module>`
    `{json_dict.update(header, val) for header, in line_data[0].items()}`
  `File "json_to_csv.py", line 11, in <setcomp>`
    `{json_dict.update(header, val) for header, in line_data[0].items()}`
`ValueError: too many values to unpack`